# How to create storage connection dynamically in azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

[image]I want to connect to multiple storage accounts dynamically using one connector (get blob content using path). That means storage account container connection string will come from variable.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the blob storage connector you can connect to the storage account with http instead and dynamically build the uri.  I created a separate Logic App to handle this that other Logic Apps can call.  Here is an example of writing to blob storage, use GET method to read.  You could parameterize the method too.  The URI is set to, you can add folders to the end of the uri as needed.

```
concat('https://<your storage account uri>/', triggerBody()?['filename'])
```

In your example you can dynamically build the uri elsewhere and pass it to this Logic App.

[image]

We actually use this method for security, allowing us to block access to the storage accounts from the internet, which doesn't allow the blob connector to work from Logic Apps either.